# Piecewise differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, piecewise

Say I have a very trivial function

$$
V\left(r\right)=\begin{cases}
-V_{0} & 0\leq r\leq R\\
0 & r>R
\end{cases} 
$$
with $V_{0}>0$ and $R>0$. I would like to let *Mathematica* solve the differential equation

$$
u''\left(r\right)+k^{2}u\left(r\right)=V\left(r\right)u\left(r\right)
$$

in the $r>0$ region with boundary conditions $u(0)=0$ and such that the solution and it's derivative match at $r=R$. Is there a simple way for this? A way generalizable to other piecewise functions? Using $k=1$ and $V_{0}=1$ I have attempted

```
DSolve[{u''[r] + u[r] (1 + UnitStep[1 - r]) == 0, u[0] == 0}, u[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

I get no result, *Mathematica* just shows back my input.

Comment: Use `Piecewise` to represent `V[r]`.  Understand, though, that `DSolve` cannot solve all ODEs.

Comment: Using `Piecewise` I get exactly the same problem. Since it's a very trivial equation, which has a simple analytic (piecewise) solution, I am hoping to get it with `DSolve`.

Comment: Try using just the variable instead of a range in the third argument: `DSolve[{u''[r] + u[r] (1 + UnitStep[1 - r]) == 0, u[0] == 0}, u[r], r]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I tried that, no benefit though.

Comment: what about NDSolve? I bet you are not really looking into solving a step potential but something more complex that most probably will not be analytically solvable.

Comment: That's true, but in future I will encounter similar easy piecewise ODEs for which I'd like, if existing (like in this case), an analytic solution.

Comment: This issue persists in Version 10.4, and I have submitted it to Wolfram as a possible bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This particular ODE can be integrated by the somewhat cumbersome means,

```
s1 = Simplify@ExpToTrig@DSolve[{u1''[r] + k^2 u1[r] + v0 u1[r] == 0, u1[0] == 0}, u1[r], 
    r, Assumptions -> k^2 + v0 > 0][[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> -I c/2
s2 = First@FullSimplify@First@DSolve[{u2''[r] + k^2 u2[r] == 0, 
    u2[r0] == u1[r] /. s1 /. r -> r0, u2'[r0] == D[u1[r] /. s1, r] /. r -> r0}, 
    u2[r], r]
s = Piecewise[{{u1[r] /. s1, 0 < r < r0}}, u2[r] /. s2]
(* Piecewise[{{c*Sin[r*Sqrt[k^2 + v0]], 0 < r < r0}}, 
   (c*Sqrt[k^2 + v0]*Cos[r0*Sqrt[k^2 + v0]]*Sin[k*(r - r0)])/k + 
   c*Cos[k*(r - r0)]*Sin[r0*Sqrt[k^2 + v0]]] *)
```

In general, if `DSolve` can integrate each region of the ODE, then the parts can be matched together as shown here.  The more fundamental question is whether `DSolve` can integrate ODEs with more complicated expressions for `V`.  In general, `DSolve` can solve only those ODEs that have known solutions.  Otherwise, `NDSolve` must be used, and it can handle discontinuous expressions for `V`.

Comment: What you wrote was the solution to $u''\left(r\right)+k^{2}u\left(r\right)=V\left(r\right)$
  but I need $u''\left(r\right)+k^{2}u\left(r\right)=V\left(r\right)u\left(r\right)$ ...

Comment: @AntonioCox  Here is the corrected answer.

Comment: Ok, so in general I can extract each region of a piecewise function, solve for the region (assuming the integration is possible), impose the continuity conditions as you did, and then stick each piece back together. I can attempt to write a code for that. At the end, from a general solvable input piecewise function I will get a nice piecewise output, with continuity conditions automatically imposed. Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioCox  You are correct.  It is unfortunate that `DSolve` cannot handle such cases without assistance.  This is not the first time that I have seen `DSolve` struggle with seemingly straightforward ODEs.

Answer (score 8):

Well, here's an indirect way, using the value `Zeta[3]` as a proxy for a symbolic $R$, which can be replaced by `R` after `DSolve` returns.  I also put in an explicit (symbolic) initial value `up` for `u'[0]`.

```
sol = DSolve[{u''[r] + k^2 u[r] == Piecewise[{{-v0, 0 <= r <= Zeta[3]}}] u[r],
    u[0] == 0, u'[0] == up}, u, r] /. Zeta[3] -> R
(*  somewhat long solution  *)
```

Simplified:

```
u[r] /. First[sol] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check:

```
u''[r] + k^2 u[r] - Piecewise[{{-v0, 0 <= r <= R}}] u[r] /. 
   First[sol] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify
(*  0  *)
```

Comment: Incredible.  Anything that Mathematica recognizes as a real number appears to work in place of `R`, like `Pi^3` or `Gamma[Pi]`.  This suggests that `Assumptions -> r > 0 && R ∈ Reals` in `DSolve` should work, but it does not.  What do you make of this?  In any case, +1.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Solving for `u''[t]`, generally the first step of (N)DSolve, yields two `ConditionalExpression` solutions, which should be a single `Piecewise` solution, imo. I think that splits the solving process into two branches (similar to your solution) that `DSolve` struggles with. But constructing the `Piecewise` solution by hand doesn't work either: `Block[{R(*=Zeta[3]*)}, DSolve[{u''[r] == Piecewise[{{-(k^2*u[r]), (R ∈ Reals && r > R) || (R ∈ Reals && r < 0)}}, -u[r] - k^2*u[r]], u[0] == u0, Derivative[1][u][0] == up}, u[r], r, Assumptions -> R > 0]]` -- (1/0 error, unless `R` is numeric)

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestion. Imposing also the `u'[0] == up` condition (and avoiding symbolic expressions) did the job , compared to  `u[0] == 0` alone. It's a bit sad that one has to use tricks like Zeta[3] to "cheat" Mathematica, but as long as it works it's ok. For sure in future versions it will be more flexible.