# Scoping problem with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, core-language

I'm trying to solve a more complex problem , however , this simple problem can represent well :

```
b := a;

s1[a_] := First @ NDSolve[{y'[x] == -b y[x], y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 5}]

c = y[x] /. s1[a] /. x -> 5

s2[a_] := First @ NDSolve[{z'[x] == -c z[x], z[0] == 1}, z[x], {x, 0, 5}]

z[x] /. s2[1] /. x -> 5
```

I wish to solve the `s1` equation as a function of `b` and later specify `a` only when the `s2` equation is to be solved.

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Your example may be to simple.  For what you have in the question, use `ParametricNDSolve` to obtain a solution in terms of `b`, and then insert the value of `a` for `b`.

Comment: Please could you show me how to make your suggestion in the above example ?

Comment: Almost the same example is explored in the "Basic Examples" of the documentation for `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Certainly, the `s1` equation replicates one in the documentation.  However, the `s2` equation, added in a subsequent edit, differs in that it uses the `s1` parametric solution as part of its ODE.  Although one might argue that the difference is not significant, we both know from [108938](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108938/1063) that Mathematica sometimes goes astray when combining functions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey If this question conveys a meaning to you, perhaps you could edit it to clarify.  As it stands, there are too many ambiguities, and I would have to guess what is intended.  Since the OP's setup fails at the first step, I thought my recommendation was a good place to start.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Done.  Have I hit the mark?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, it's clearer.  I guess it's up the OP to say whether it is what was meant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly (and I may not), the solution is

```
s1 = First@ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == -b y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, b];
s2 = First@ParametricNDSolve[{z'[x] == -(y[a][5] /. s1) z[x], z[0] == 1}, 
    z, {x, 0, 5}, a];
z[1][5] /. s2
(* 0.966871 *)
```

Verification

Because this particular set of equations can be solved symbolically, the result just obtained can be verified by

```
s3 = First@DSolve[{y'[x] == -b y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}] /. b -> a;
s4 = First@DSolve[{z'[x] == -(y[5] /. s3) z[x], z[0] == 1}, z, {x, 0, 5}];
N[z[5] /. s4 /. a -> 1]
(* 0.966871 *)
```

as desired.